# JRE/Tomcat High CPU Utilization 100% on Linux

Tags: java, ubuntu, tomcat, jvm, geoserver

Geoserver 2.16.1 is running on Tomcat 9.0.30 in Linux 5.3.0-53-generic (Ubuntu 18.04 64bit) machine with Corei9 processor + 32GB RAM. Recently I have faced some problem with CPU uses 100%. When I restart the tomcat server it is running good, but after one day or a few hour again same problem arise (CPU uses 100%) and that problem make my site slow. **Java / Tomcat services are consuming high % of CPU utilization** as shown below.

[image]

Tomcat configurations are,

[image]

[image]

My Geoserver configurations are as follows,

[image]

Comment: It can be useful to look at what those CPUs are doing, specifically examine thread stacks, e.g. via `jstack` or `jcmd Thread.print`. Is the app expected to do any significant work? Any scheduled tasks or something like that? For how long the high CPU utilization goes on? Until you force the restart?

Comment: Sure Juraj, I will check with jstack / jcmd Thread.print and come back. No, this app is not doing any significant work and no scheduled task. It is serving the data to map page whenever it is accessed by users. Currently there is no users as it is in staging server. Yes, until I restart the server/service.